# C# IS possible to name a method in class named new?

Tags: c#

example:

```
class document
{
    public void new()
    {
    }
    public void save()
    {
    }

}
```

visual studio claim that new is red-underlined with error.
I need that all is lower-cased to arrange cleanliness

> **For those seen this Questions:*
>   **(Answer)C# Naming rule violation: Words must be begin with Upper Cases!!!**

Comment: No keywords are reserved you can't use them for user defined function names

Comment: How about 'CreateNew' instead ?

Comment: That's why Microsoft has always pushed for UpperCamelCase as the standard for publicly exposed methods and properties. It's clean and there's less of a chance it'll overlap with a key word.

Comment: I wouldn't call coding against C# naming conventions "cleanliness". Just use camel case to avoid confusing 99% other C# developers. Also, `New` is a rather bad name for a method returning `void`, and I am presuming this code should belong inside the constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NO, you can't since `new` is a keywoard. But, YES, you can escape keywords by `@` if accepted.

```
class document
{
    public void test()
    {
        this.@new();
    }

    public void @new()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

C# suggests using upper camel case in class name and method name.

Since keywords are in lower cases, upper camel case names, like `void New()`, are unaffected.

Comment: "Yup, yup, yes you *can,* but you **really** don't want to.  You're creating a situation that, while acceptable to the *compiler,* will cause many employees who will one day follow you to curse your name.  **;-)**  A far better alternative, if you can possibly do it, is simply to pick a different name for your method.  (How about, say, `initialize` and `terminate`?)  If the language that you're using has staked a proprietary claim on a particular word, stay well away from that word. *"Many future employees will thank you ..."*

Comment: Reason accepted: C# Naming rule violation: Words must be begin with Upper Cases.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot use keywords as identifiers.  See article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx.